# wordpress writing panel in theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to make a public blog, Where user can write from the frontend after login.

Basically in wordpress, after login, Users being redirect to wp-admin, the Dashboard. And there they have the 'new post' functionality. But i want to keep that away from my bloggers. They will login from the custom login panel in the sidebar and they will have a new post link there, which will take them to www.domainname.com/new-post or something like that. There they will have the full functionality of wordpress content editor. Upload, Main text-area with Editor, Tag and Category. All of them in the frontend so that i don't have to show them the wp-admin section.

is there any way to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that what you describes can be easily done with this plug-in:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-user-frontend/